# How to serialize a object in the HttpHandler class

Tags: java, serialization, response, httpserver

I have to serialize an object and send it from a httpserver
i already know how to send a string from the server to the client,but i don't know how to send a object

So i have this code :

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
    server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
    server.start();
}
static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
        String response = "This is the response";

        //this part here shows how to send a string
        //but i need to send an object here
        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes());
        os.close();
    }
}
}
```

so i tried to search google but no results,and i tried to change the code (mechanically without knowing well what im doing as im not used to HttpServer's in java)
this way :

```
SendResponse obj = new SendResponse();
                    ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream();
                    t.sendResponseHeaders(200, objOut);

                    objOut.writeObject(obj);
                    objOut.close();
```

but eclipse shows me an error which tells me that the ObjectOutputStream() constructor is not visible and that httpExchange is not applicable for the  arguments (int,ObjectInputStream)

Do you have any idea how i can fix this ?
Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of trying different things 
you have just to replace the

`t.sendResponseHeaders(200, objOut);`

with

`t.sendResponseHeaders(200,0);`

as mentioned by user ***cyon*** [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194755/java-io-eofexception-error-on-object-serialization-with-httphandler)

Answer (score 1):

You have accesible the constructor with one OutputStream as parameter

```
ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream( the http or any other output stream here );
```

The constructor of ObjectOutputStream sends some header bytes and the constructor of ObjectInputStream expects these header bytes. You should either create a new ObjectOutputStream and a new ObjectInputStream for every object, or create only one ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream for all the objects.

A more simple alternative could be [google gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) It´s easy to use and it converts a java class to json string and the inverse way too.

Comment: i have done it like that i changed the "the http or any other output stream here" with obj but it shows me an error saying that could not instantiate an OutputStream