# java.io.EOFException error on object serialization with HttpHandler

Tags: java, exception, networking, stream

I am trying to serialize an object in a `HttpHandler` class.

I have 2 files, `Server3.java`:

```
package server3;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class Server3 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(3333), 0);
server.createContext("/", new MyHandler());
server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
server.start();
}

static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
        String response = "Kjo eshte nje pergjigje nga serveri! n";

        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes());
        os.close();

        Personat obj = new Personat();
        ObjectOutputStream objOut = new     ObjectOutputStream(t.getResponseBody());
        objOut.writeObject(obj);
        objOut.close();
}
}
}
class Personat implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
int ID=3;
String Name="Andi";
}
```

and `Client3.java`:

```
package server3;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
//te gjithe personat qe jan ne database me nej objekt 
public class Client3 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:3333");
        HttpURLConnection s = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        s.setDoOutput(true);
        s.setDoInput(true);
        s.setRequestMethod("POST");
        s.setUseCaches(false);

        InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        int c;
        while ((c = br.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char) c);
        }
        ObjectInputStream ios = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        Personat oin = (Personat) ios.readObject();
        String emri=oin.Name;
        System.out.println(emri);
        ios.close();
        s.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
        System.out.print(ex);
    }
}
  }
```

But when I run it eclipse shows me

```
java.io.EOFException Kjo eshte nje pergjigje nga serveri! njava.io.EOFException`
```

and I cant understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to fit both the string `response` and the object into `response.length()` bytes. What happens is that only `response.length()` bytes are sent and so if you try to read more you get the `EOFException`.

If you instead set the `responseLength` parameter to be 0 it will allow you to transmit an arbitrary amount of data

```
t.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
```

You also shouldn't close the stream if you are going to write more data into it. Don't call `os.close()` until all the writing is complete.

Comment: And a big thank you !!!! I have like 2 days (16h) of work to make this work ,and i just could't !!! Finally now i can finish my work !!!So again THANK YOU !!!